# Can I set environment variables programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm writing some code using Swift 3.0 in Xcode that involves a login page. 
I'd like to set an environment variable named CurrentUser. Is there a way to define the environment var in the scheme and set the value of the variable programmatically once I log in?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nope. `NSProcessInfo`’s `environment` property is read-only. And there is a good reason for that.

With Swift you know you can define global vars shared across your whole app, right? Why would you need to mess with the env?

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsprocessinfo/1417911-environment?language=objc

BTW, we typically use the Keychain to store login information like username and password, since it’s a secure, system-provided, persistent key-value datastore.

Check out:
https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift

Comment: All good to know. Thank you

Comment: So, if I store something in keychain, does it become available to the whole app? Or do I have to create my keychain globally to have access to it in different parts of the app

Comment: @Johan Elbaz it becomes available in not only your whole apps, but any apps published under your developer account that are installed at the same time. But if someone uninstalls your apps, it gets deleted by the system.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can set environment variables programmatically for the current process (which will also be inherited by child processes, by default). You can call the [`setenv()`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getenv.3.html) function to do it.

This **will** affect the dictionary returned by future queries of the `environment` property of `NSProcessInfo`. You can, of course, also retrieve values using the `getenv()` function.

Comment: But you cannot override values that were already set at launch, like by scheme arguments.

Comment: Of course you can. The only issue is if the environment variable is queried by something during startup before you have the opportunity to modify it. You won't be able to go back in time and change decisions that were already made at that point, obviously.

Comment: Oh, interesting, thanks. I was not aware of that. So can a static library (that you include in your app) call `setenv()` and override any environment settings that your app might be depending on?

Comment: Of course. Code you include in your app (via any means) can do anything your own code can do. But, it would be pretty unusual for an app to depend on environment variable values because you don't get a predictable environment on launch in any case.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. Whether it messes up the environment or not... is irrelevant. For example, I need to make some legacy tests that use environment pass - so I don't really care about what happens to the system. Other use-cases are different, but in the end it's important that we still have access to the OS